# Passing a bool variable as a parameter to a function expecting a BOOL parameter in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, boolean

Take this sample code:

```
void CChristianLifeMinistryDiscussionsDlg::SetControlStates()
{
    if (m_pEntry == nullptr)
        return;

    bool bClass1 = false, bClass2 = false;
    m_pEntry->GetAuxiliaryClasses(bClass1, bClass2);

    m_cbBrothersC1.EnableWindow(bClass1 ? TRUE : FALSE);
    m_cbBrothersC2.EnableWindow(bClass2 ? TRUE : FALSE);

}
```

`EnableWindow` expects a parameter of type `BOOL`. It is never clear to me if it is acceptable to just pass the value of my `bool` variable in this situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [`BOOL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types) is a type alias for an `int`. A value of type `bool` can be [implicitly converted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) to a value of type `int`. This is called *integral promotion*, and well defined: The value `false` becomes 0 and the value `true` becomes 1.

Passing a value of type `bool` to a function that expects an argument of type `BOOL` (i.e. `int`) is safe and well defined.